# Why is the square of the average of a set of positive numbers not always bigger than the average of the squares of the same set of positive numbers?

Tags: mean, set-theory

Why is the square of the average of a set of positive numbers not always bigger than the average of the squares of the same set of positive numbers?

I am not talking about in an asymptotic case.

Comment: Sometimes numbers are equal to each other

Comment: and sometimes you only have one number

Comment: $\text{Var}(X) =E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2] -(E[X])^2$

Comment: The variance is never less than zero.

Comment: Indeed, as it is the expectation of a non-negative random variable.  That is why $E[X^2] \ge (E[X])^2$, equivalent to "the average of the squares is never less than the square of the average".  When are they equal?

Comment: Check  the keyword `Jensen's inequality`